# webforms post in a Sitecore application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, sitecore

Before reading my question I would recommend you to first read this article: http://blog.karbyn.com/articles/creating-a-custom-sitecore-administration-page-with-authentication/
. As in the article, I am working on implementing an admin backend for my sitecore built web application. So far; I have an action method called Page_Load which is responsible for rendering a form to the View - which enables Sitecore content users to query the Database, filtering the entries by DateTime. FormPost is empty and I will explain why shortly.

```
public partial class AdminUtility : AdminPage
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CheckSecurity(true); //Required!
        base.OnInit(e);

    }

    protected void FormPost(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

}
```

Page_Load renders this form. Because of Sitecore routing I was having difficulty posting the data to a different aspx page. Hence, Is it possible to post the form directly back to the same controller class but this time the method "FormPost" can handle the request.

```
 <form action="FormPost" id="form1" runat="server">

        <p> Date From: <input type="text" name="DateFrom" id="DateFrom"> </p>

        <p> Date To: <input type="text"name="DateTo" id="DateTo"> </p>

        <input type="submit" />

  </form>
```

Comment: This might help - [How to: Post ASP.NET Web Forms Page to a Different Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Form attribute, try to place the onclick directly on the button as shown below using ASP.NET user control:

```
<div id="form1">

        <p> Date From: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="DateFrom" /> </p>

        <p> Date To: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="DateTo" /> </p>

        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitButton" Text="Process" OnClick="FormPost"/>

</div>
```

Comment: Yep. Either this, or use the PostBackUrl attribute on the button itself.